# Stripes framework sample example using netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, stripes

please can you give sample example for stripes framework using netbeans IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The Stripes framework works the same in all Java IDE's. You might want to take a look at the example [Stripes example code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stripes_(framework)) @wikipedia or the [Quick start code](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Quick+Start+Guide) at the Stripes website.